# Logging to a file in Blazor WASM

Tags: logging, blazor, serilog, blazor-webassembly, serilog-sinks-file

I am new to Blazor. I want to log to a file in client side of Blazor WASM. I tried using serilog and serilog.sink.file. But I don't see any logs written to a file. I also don'see any errors. Is it because Blazor WASM operates in the browser sandbox which cannot access local filesystem.Is there any way to log to file from Blazor WASM.

The code I tried for configuring in Main:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Is(logLevel)
            .WriteTo.File(path: @"C:\Users\abc\logs.log",
                          rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day,
                          rollOnFileSizeLimit: true,
                          fileSizeLimitBytes: 10 * 1024 * 1024)                
            .CreateLogger();
 Log.Information("testing");
```

Comment: I think you've answered your own question - Is it because Blazor WASM operates in the browser sandbox which cannot access local filesystem.  You can log to the browser console through javascript with `console.write`, but otherwise it's log back to a service on a server.

Comment: Blazor WASM runs in a Browser. Any kind of Browser. Where is `C:\Users\abc` on Linux?  On iOS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to log blazor WASM in file directly. Because codes fully  run in browser. You also can use other serilog sinks like browserconsole or blazor relay that provide special for blazor

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write your log to a file on the client you can log to console then launch chrome with an option to redirect logs:

`--enable-logging=stderr --v=1 > log.txt 2>&1`

It's easier to log to console and use F12 in your browser to view the logs.
I use Microsoft.Logging.Extensions:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging

Then I configure in Program.cs with:

```cs
            builder.Services.AddLogging(builder => builder
                .SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Debug)
                .AddFilter("Microsoft", LogLevel.Warning)
                .AddFilter("System", LogLevel.Warning)
            );
```

Then I inject and call the logger with:

```cs
        [Inject] protected ILogger<MyClassIamLoggingFrom> Logger { get; set; }

        Logger?.LogDebug("Fetching install data");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is all theoretical, but I see no reason why it wouldn't work...

If you want to log to a file to gain persistence for your log messages (maybe you are doing some troubleshooting?) then you could log to `localStorage`. I use `Blazored.LocalStorage` for this, making it very easy to do from C#.

Note that each entry in localStorage has a length limit, but it seems like in many modern browsers that limit is at least 5 MB. [What is the max size of localStorage values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989284/what-is-the-max-size-of-localstorage-values)

So, first you would create your own custom logging provider that logs messages to a `localStorage` entry.  I would probably keep concatenating log messages to the same `localStorage` entry, otherwise it would get out of hand fast.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/logging?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Then add your logger (in Program.cs for client-side Blazor), something like this:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ILoggerProvider, CustomLoggerProvider>(services => 
{ return new CustomLoggerProvider(); });
```

Then inject and use as you would normally:

```
[Inject] ILoggerProvider loggerProvider { get; set; }
. . .
ILogger logger = loggerProvider.CreateLogger( GetType().FullName );
. . .
logger.LogInformation("Your message here");
```